# using while loop the page keep loading over and over (codewars problem)

Tags: algorithm, loops, while-loop, task, loading

heyy guys   i m trying to solve Factorial decomposition (codewars task )
well  some numbers work with me untill i reach number 23 the page keep looping over and over someone help me please

```
function decomp(n) {
  let c =[]
  let sum =1
 for(let i=n;i>=1;i--){
   sum*=i
 }
 let k= 2
 
 while(k<=sum){
  if(sum%k!==0){
  k++}
  while(sum%k==0){
    c.push(k)
sum = sum/k

} 
 }
  return c.join('*')
}
```

the function works good until i reach the number 23  the keep loading over and over  ,  the tasks is about  the function is decomp(n) and should return the decomposition of n! into its prime factors in increasing order of the primes, as a string.

factorial can be a very big number (4000! has 12674 digits, n can go from 300 to 4000).

In Fortran - as in any other language - the returned string is not permitted to contain any redundant trailing whitespace: you can use dynamically allocated character strings.

example

n = 12; decomp(12) -> "2^10 * 3^5 * 5^2 * 7 * 11"

since 12! is divisible by 2 ten times, by 3 five times, by 5 two times and by 7 and 11 only once.

n = 22; decomp(22) -> "2^19 * 3^9 * 5^4 * 7^3 * 11^2 * 13 * 17 * 19"

n = 25; decomp(25) -> 2^22 * 3^10 * 5^6 * 7^3 * 11^2 * 13 * 17 * 19 * 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

23! cannot be exactly expressed in [double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), which JavaScript uses for its numbers.

However, you don't need to compute `n!`. You just need to factorize each number and concat their factorization.

Actually, you don't even need to factorize each number. Note that given `n` and `p`, there are `(n/p)` numbers no greater than `n` that are multiples of `p`, `(n/(p*p))` that are multiples of `p*p`, etc.

```js
function *primes(n) {
  // Sieve of Eratosthenes 
  const isPrime = Array(n + 1).fill(true);
  isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = false;
  for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    if (isPrime[i]) {
      yield i;
      for (let j = i * i; j <= n; j += i)
        isPrime[j] = false;
    }
  }
}

function decomp(n) {
  let s = n + '! =';
  for (const p of primes(n)) {
    let m = n, c = 0;
    // There are (n/p) numbers no greater than n that are multiples of p
    // There are (n/(p*p)) numbers no greater than n that are multiples of p*p
    // ...
    while (m = ((m / p) | 0)) {
      c += m;
    }
    s += (p == 2 ? ' ' : ' * ') + p + (c == 1 ? '' : '^' + c);
  }  
  return s;
}

console.log(decomp(12))
console.log(decomp(22))
console.log(decomp(23))
console.log(decomp(24))
console.log(decomp(25))
```

Comment: thank you sirr so much ,  exuse me  i m not verry familiar with generators and iterrators  well i didn't understand  what  yield i means exactly in this example  i understand that the 2 first items are filled with false   and starting from index 2 it's true